# Twitter API - which Library?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, twitter

I'm new to objective-c/cocoa and I want to build a simple app using Twitter API.
I only want to access the Followers of the user and because of that I don't think I will need a complex library like `MGTwitterEngine`.

Is there any Engine out there to my needs or should I use `MGTwitterEngine`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend getting some experience with MGTwitterEngine.  Even if you don't have a use for the entire library, I'm sure you'll want to take advantage of it later on down the road once you see what it's capable of.  You can even find an entire tutorial from start to finish on [creating a twitter client with the MGTwitterEngine](http://brandontreb.com/creating-a-twitter-client-for-osx-part-1/).

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I need to get started :)